# writing pandas dataframe into csv file

Tags: pandas, encoding, character-encoding

I am trying to write pandas dataframe which has German text into csv file. Here is the the relevant snippet:

```
data =p.DataFrame(Inform)
data = data.fillna("NA")
data=data.transpose()
data.to_csv("./Info.csv",encoding='utf-8')
```

The text was obtained through `soup = BeautifulSoup(r, from_encoding='utf-8')`. When I print the text in console it produces properly decoded text - however in the csv the text is not decoded (e.g., "GesamtflÃ¤che"). I tried some other encodings but they don't seem to work either.

Comment: Can you show how you get from `soup` to `Inform`?  What happens if you declare the encoding in creating the dataframe (`pd.DataFrame(Inform, encoding='utf-8')`)?

Comment: Inform is a dictionary where I store crawled information. For example: `Inform[str(key)]["Description"] =soup.find("div", {"id": "div_Description"}).text.strip()`. Following your suggestion, when I add `data =p.DataFrame(Inform, encoding='utf-8')` I get an error `__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoding'`.